# I can't change platform in configuration manager in Visual 2012

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7, visual-studio-2012, 32bit-64bit

I run an Asp.net Site one of my classes gone out of control since I Changed using Visual 2010 to 2012.
Right now I am having this error.

> "Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID  failed due
>   to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered"

My searches suggested me that IIS manager can run 32 bit applications must be true.
I fixed the problem in the server but on the developer machine I can't change it.

I tried to change the platform through the configuration manager. But it only shows "ANY CPU"
Should I look for a local IIS options. I looked there and changed its 32 bit applications rule too.
Am i missing something ?

Answer (score 1):

From what you told, you already checked the "Enable 32-Bit Applications" in IIS 7 in the Application Pool and that should have solved your problem.

To compile your application in 32-Bit, open the application properties and in the Build tab there must be a "Platform target" drop down. Select x86 and rebuild your solution. I believe this should be enough.